# Можно ли присваивать класс тегу <br>?

Tags: html, html5

Вопрос по сути глупый, поэтому не сильно хочется тратить время еще и на объяснение ситуации, где мне это понадобилось. Просто интересно, насколько это валидно и вообще разрешено ли?

Под сомнение ставит тот факт, что я еще ни у кого не видел `<br>` с классами :)

Хотя оно и понятно, надобности не возникало.

Comment: Скорее всего да, можно выбрать высоту разрыва.

Comment: да можно например так <br class="hidden-xs"> (для bootsrap 3)

Comment: Классы могут быть у абсолютно любых тегов, и даже у br надобность иногда есть

Comment: Все, спасибо! Сомнения развеяны)

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. А некоторых браузерах (как минимум, в хроме) его даже стилизовать можно, если `content` указать.

```css
.skip {
  display: none;
}

.styled {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
123<br>
456<br class="styled">
789<br class="skip">
012
```

Answer (score 0):

Он же ничего не отображает. У него есть только атрибут `<br clear="свойство">` И то им ни кто никогда не пользуется. Так что функционал для управления тегом имеется.

Comment: Атрибут clear устарел и заменён на CSS-свойство clear. А это CSS-свойство можно установить через — сюрприз! — класс

Comment: При использовании js в редких случаях, например, в моем, очень помогает как раз присвоение класса.
Насчет стилей вполне хватает и самого тега, с этим согласен.

Comment: Я и сам ни когда не задумывался об этом. И в принципе никогда не пользуюсь этим тегом. Обычно, все элементы верстки управляются через блоки. Если нужно что то перенести то <p> или <span> использовал. Пользуюсь им только если нужно что то в самом html коде перенести, при отладке php скрипта, к примеру.

Comment: @Денис, визуально да, отступами можно добиться того же эффекта.
Но есть одно НО: если важно, чтобы при копировании текста между параграфами или чем-нибудь другим был реальный разрыв строки, то тут стили уже не помогут. Вот для этого как раз <br> самое то.